# C# program to crash system to halt instantly (for system recoverability testing), simulating serious hardware error

Tags: c#

I need to run tests on system recoverability which includes suddenly crashing a system *without warning* ("hard crash", no shutdown workaround).

I'm looking for something as close as possible to a serious hardware error that just fully crashes the system (blue screen HALT or worse, e.g .sudden reboot similar to non-recoverable memory/cpu errors).

How could I do something like this in C# (probably unmanaged code?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find flipping the power switch (on the wall socket) works perfectly for this solution - especially when I only meant to turn the monitor off.

If you need to do it from the keyboard, check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139) for a way to generate a BSOD.

EDIT: a quick google suggests there are 3 ways:

- write a device driver and dereference a null pointer
- do the keyboard shortcut described above
- run windbg in kernel mode and type .crash at the prompt.

Comment: Need to be able to do it remotely...    Plus I'd rather not 'generate' the BSOD the friendly microsoft-approved way but actually crash the machine by doing something (?) it can't handle.

Comment: simple device driver it is then: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=20 or download a DDK sample and 'break' it.

Comment: what gbjbaanb said. You can download the WDK there: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx

Answer (score 2):

Find and kill the process running csrss.exe. That will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the easiest way to do it, espacially if you want to build it into some kind of automated test (which I guess that you will when you say that, "How could I do something like this in C#") is to create a new AppDomain.

I.e. your automated test will create a new AppDomain, and then startup your application inside the new AppDomain. Your automated test can then unload the AppDomain. That will completely abort the application. It will be close to 100% identical to what happens during hardware crash, so it will allow you to test your recovery code. I don't think that it will leave your file system corrupt however (thus not 100% identical)

Note that if you are not used to working with multiple AppDomains, there are a few things to be aware of. E.g. when you access an object in another AppDomain, the object will be serialized across the AppDomain boundary, except if it inherits from MarshalByRefObject.

I have a similar situation, where we are testing exactly the same (recovery from an unexpected crash). Here, the code that launches a new AppDomain creates a "bootstrapper" object inside the new AppDomain. This bootstrapper is a MarshalByRefObject specialization and has the responsibility of executing application startup logic.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to manually BSOD a machine. A tutorial is available [here](http://thesysadmin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!CAB4C4A1DD3A835!158.entry). After setting up the necessary registry entries you can crash the machine by pressing Right Ctrl and Scroll Lock.

Comment: Is there a way to actually crash the machine? (this still appears like a friendly way to do it as the system 'knows' about it being user initiated!)

Comment: Not unless you use a special hardware or drivers. The only difference of this from a "normal" BSOD is the code it reports, the machine is stopped in exactly the same way as if the keyboard driver crashed.

Comment: Note that this "friendly" BSOD is designed for this kind of testing, it's the primary reason of its existence.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something new today and totally crashed my system successfully... Check out my code..

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process[] processess = Process.GetProcesses();//Get all the process in your system

    foreach (var process in processess)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
            process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal; //sets all the process to below normal priority
            process.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(E.Message + " :: [ " + process.ProcessName + " ] Could not be killed");
        }

    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still curious after this time, the simplest code is this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("csrss")[0].Kill();
```

It kills `csrss.exe` which is need for the system to work.